# same id with different names - get longer name

Tags: sql, postgresql

My situation, i have:

```
id     name
1      jack S
1      jack Soon
1      jack Son
2      Ray J
2      Ray James Charles
2      Ray J C
3      Mark
```

I need to select only one ID with the longer name, or at lesat only one name.
Result something like:

```
id     name
1      jack Soon
2      Ray James Charles
3      Mark
```

Comment: What to do in case of ties (e.g. 'Jack S.' vs. 'J. Soon')? Pick one arbitrarily or show two rows or show one row with both names? Or apply some rule which to pick? Can the same name appear multiple times, e.g. 1|'Jack Soon' twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation or a window function:

```
select id,
       max(name) keep (dense_rank first order by length(name) desc)
from t
group by id;
```

Or:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by length(name) desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id = t.id and length(name) > length(t.name)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=25b803e5af6f56ce4f381c9329393a25).
Results:

```
> id | name             
> -: | :----------------
>  1 | jack Soon        
>  2 | Ray James Charles
>  3 | Mark
```